# Python quitting unexpectedly

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, matplotlib

I'm running Python 2.7, using ipython 5.1.0 on a Mac OSX 10.9.5
I'm having a problem which occurs most often when I use matplotlib.pyplot, but has happened when I'm using processes from pandas.

Two examples of the code I've run that leads to the crash:
1)after running an mcmc simulation, which uses the pandas pymc - running this within a particular package called HDDM so code is this:

```
m.find_starting_values() 
m.sample(15000, burn=5000, dbname='traces.db', db='pickle')
```

2) Also happened after trying to plot using matlibplot

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, xlabel='RT', ylabel='count',title='RTdistributions')
for i, subj_data in data.groupby('subj_idx'):
subj_data.rt.hist(bins=20, histtype='step', ax=ax)
```

The problem is that python crashes and I get the message "Python has quit unexpectedly". I've pasted the full error message details here https://gist.github.com/anonymous/688186089d164ccbac5857a007efafdb

This was happening, so I tried updating the relevant packages and updated ipython (I don't want to update from python 2.7). Does anyone have any thoughts about what could be going on?
Many thanks, Claire

Comment: What is `m` and `plt`?

Comment: sorry - m is the name of a specified model (so this shouldn't be relevant to teh error), plt is part of matlibplot. I matlibplot like this: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt